# How to print a woocommerce notice after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got the following code which updates a VAT Numebr which is stored against the user meta. I was wondering if anyone knew how I could add Woocommerce Success message which says something along the lines of 'VAT Number Successfully Updated' once the form has been submitted and the page has refrwshed. With my current code, it works but the message only appears once I've refreshed the page after I've pressed save on the form.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['vat_number'])) {
        $vat_number = $_GET['vat_number'];
        update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'vat_number', $vat_number);
        $message = 'VAT Number successfully updated';
        $notice_type= success;
        wc_add_notice( $message, $notice_type ); 
        } ?>

        <?php $vat_number = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'vat_number', true ); ?>

        <form name="setprices" action="#" method="GET">

        <label for="lowPrice">Vat Number: </label>
        <input type="text" id="vat_number" name="vat_number" value="<?php echo $vat_number ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="update"/>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `wc_add_notice()` function saves a notice for the next view. So that's normal behaviour. Your code should fire, save the notice and refresh or redirect the user.

Comment: Could you advise me on how to do this please

Comment: @Neil If I use  wc_print_notice( $message, $notice_type ); it works as I need, but the message is not at the top of the page

Comment: Success is the default notice type so `wc_add_notice($message)` should be sufficient unless you are on a template that doesn't print WooCommerce notices.

Comment: Make sure your template has `wc_print_notices();` somewhere in it in order to print the notices.